# Loop over a FormCollection to get radiobutton SelectedAnswers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, radio-button, formcollection

How can I get the values of radio buttons that are named predicatively as Questions[i] using a form collection?

In the form collection

```
Questions[0].ObjectId
Questions[0].SelectedAnswer
Questions[1].ObjectId
Questions[1].SelectedAnswer
Questions[2].ObjectId
Questions[2].SelectedAnswer
3 - 13 ... etc...
Questions[14].ObjectId
Questions[14].SelectedAnswer
(a bunch of other stuff)
```

In the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostResults(FormCollection form)
{
    List<SelectedAnswer> selectedAnswers = new List<SelectedAnswer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        //this is the part that is not working...
        selectedAnswers.Add(new SelectedAnswer() { questionId = form["Questions"][i].ObjectId; answerId = form["Questions"][i].SelectedAnswer}                
    }
    //continue to do other stuff
}
```

My ultimate goal is to save the selected values to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
     long x = Int64.Parse(form[String.Format("Questions[{0}].ObjectId", i)]);
     long y = Int64.Parse(form[String.Format("Questions[{0}].SelectedAnswer", i)]);
  if (x > 0 && y > 0)
   {
     selectedAnswers.Add(new SelectedAnswer() { questionId = x, answerId = y });
   }
 }
```